# Javascript: Fast way to convert colored image to zeros and ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, matrix, converters

I'm trying to convert an colored image like this one...

[image: image 1]

...into a matrix of ones and zeros to get as result something like this:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111110000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111110000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000000000111111000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000011110000000000111111000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000111111000000000011111000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000111111100000000011111000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000011111100000000011111000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000011111110000000011111000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111000000011111100000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111000000011111100000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111100000001111100000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111110000001111100000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111110000001111100000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000100000000000000111111000001111100000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000111000000000000111111100001111110000000000000
0000000000000000000000000001111110000000000011111100001111110000000000000
0000000000000000000000000011111111000000000001111110000111110000000000000
0000000000000000000000000011111111110000000001111111000111110000000000000
0000000000000000000000000001111111111100000000111111000111110000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000011111111110000000011111100111111000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000111111111100000011111110111111000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000011111111111000001111110000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000111111111110000111110000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111000111000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111110010000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000011000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000111111000000000000011111111000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000111111111100000000000111110000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000111111111111110000000011110000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000111111111111111111000000100000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000011111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111000000000000000000000000000
0000000000001111000000000000000000111111111111001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000000000000000000000011111111001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000000000000000000000000011110001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000011111110000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000011111111111111111000000000001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000011111111111111111111111110001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000011111111111111111111111110001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000011111111111111111111111110001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000000011111111111111111111110001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000000000000000000111111111100001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000000000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000000000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000011111111111111111111111100001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000011111111111111111111111100001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000011111111111111111111111100001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000011111111111111111111111100001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000011111111111111111111111100001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000000000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000000000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000000000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111000000000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000
0000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

So I've developed this code to get a result like above:

> You can find a fiddle here *(I got a security error when I try to add the code as StackOverflow-CodeSnippet / jsfiddle)* [fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/7a6xmgwp/1/).

```
Element.prototype.ImageTo2Bit = function() {
  var img = this,canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.width = canvas.width = img.width;
  ctx.height = canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width , img.height);
  var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data;
  console.log(image_data);
  var result=[];
  for(var i = 0; i < image_data.length; i=i+4){
    var luma = 0.2126 * image_data[i] + 0.7152 * image_data[i+1] + 0.0722 * image_data[i+2];
    if (luma > 200) result.push('1');
    else result.push('0');
  }
  var array=listToMatrix(result,img.width).map(a => [a.join('')]);
  array = array.concat.apply([],array);
  return array.join('\n');
};


function listToMatrix(list, elementsPerSubArray) {
    var matrix = [], i, k;
    for (i = 0, k = -1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (i % elementsPerSubArray === 0) {
            k++;
            matrix[k] = [];
        } matrix[k].push(list[i]);
    } return matrix;
}

var img = new Image();
img.src= 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPDlQ.png';
img.onload = function() {
  img.width=Math.round(img.width/7);
  img.height=Math.round(img.height/7);
  console.log(img.ImageTo2Bit());
};
```

---

However, for me the code is working fine but I'd like to speed up the code on bigger images because It takes a **LONG while**.

Is there some alternative way to convert a big image (width:2000, height: 1500) into a 2bit Image *(zeros and ones)* to my code above?

Maybe also a js-plugin that is faster would do the job!

I hope somebody can help me, thanks!

Comment: I see 3 loops, 1 in the ImageTo2Bit function, 1 in ListToMatrix, and a call to map. This could probably be done in just the one loop.

Comment: also, instead of `for(var i = 0; i < image_data.length; i=i+4){`, try `for(var i = 0, len = image_data.length; i < len; i=i+4){`